# Despite using sudo, I am getting error while installing git

Tags: git, ubuntu

my command is this, as is given in git website

$ sudo apt update; apt install git

I got this error

$ E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)

$ E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt update; apt install git
```

This runs two separate commands: `sudo apt update` and `apt install git`. If you look at it this way, you see that `sudo` only applies to the first command. Instead do this:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install git
```

The `&&` will cause the entire command to fail if the first one fails.

Comment: Even though the other answer technically is correct, this is the safer answer because you don't become root, you just execute root privileged commands that you know for sure you want to run. See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root)

Answer (score 1):

Try to download *Git* in separate commands:

```
# allows you to run programs as root user
sudo su
```

and subsequently *update* and install *Git*

```
apt update
apt install git
```